# Kohana convert database object to int

Tags: php, orm, kohana, int

i have two values. one represents a number of objects

```
$a = $product->count_all();
```

and the other represents a value from the database:

```
$first = Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->find();
```

i need the sum between the two. the second returns the first id that satsfies the query conditions. how can i convert the $first variable to int in kohana or how can i make this sum?? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `$_ignored_columns` for it:

   > ```
   > protected $_ignored_columns = array('count');
   > ```

   So, you can initialize it
   (`$first->count = $a;`) and get as a
   model column (`$count =
   $first->count;`).
2. Create special method `get_count()` in your
   model:

   > ```
   > protected $_row_count;
   >
   > public function get_count()
   > {
   >     if ( $this->_row_count === NULL)
   >     {
   >          $this->_row_count = ORM::factory($this->_object_name)->count_all();
   >     }
   >
   >     return $this->_row_count;
   > }
   > ```

Comment: Thank you so much! but i don;t see yet how do i convert that id  $first = Model::factory('product')->sale($sale_id)->find();
 to an integer. i need a counting on one side, and trasnforming this query result (which is an id) to an integer.

Comment: Ahh, sorry :) All you need is a $first->pk() call, which will return PK value from ORM model.